# Find the possible values of $t$ such that there is atleast one $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Find the possible values of $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there is atleast one $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=3$ and

$$|z-(t+(t-1)i| \le 3$$ and

$$|z-(-2t+(t+1)i| \gt 3$$

My Try:

I have choosen $z=3 \cos \theta+i 3 \sin \theta$ and the given inequalities becomes

$$(3 \cos \theta-t)^2+(3 \sin \theta+1-t)^2 \le 9$$ and

$$(3 \cos \theta+2t)^2+(3 \sin \theta-1-t)^2 \gt 9$$ expanding first inequality we get

$$2t^2-(2+6 \cos \theta+6 \sin \theta)t+1+6 \sin \theta \le 0$$

but its very tedious to solve this inequality, any clue here?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Think geometrically!! You are given a circle $\lvert z \rvert=3$ and two lines $y=x-1$ and $y=-x/2+1$. You want points that lie on this circle and are at a distance $\leq 3$ from the first line and a distance $> 3$ from the second line. Look at the following picture and now mark the regions on the circle which satisfies the distance requirements. This can help you to solve the problem but keep in mind that both lines have been parametrized by the same $t$.

[image]

Comment: Ok fine as you said i have used perpendicular distance from any point on the circle say $(3 \cos \theta, 3 \sin \theta)$ to the line $x-y-1=0$ given by $$\left|\frac{3 \cos \theta -3 \sin \theta -1}{\sqrt{2}}\right| \le 3$$ which gives $$\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}}-1 \le \cos \left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \le 1$$ so does it not mean there are infinite points on the circle